# Taipy visual elements not displaying properly

Tags: python, user-interface, charts, markdown, taipy

Taipy visual elements don't behave as usual. I can not see them; they are being replaced by a strange syntax.

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui
from math import cos, exp

value = 10

page = """
        Markdown
        # Taipy *Demo*

        Value: <|{value}|text|>

        <|{value}|slider|>

        <|{compute_data(value)}|chart|>
        """

def compute_data(decay:int)->list:
    return [cos(i/6) * exp(-i*decay/600) for i in range(100)]


Gui(page).run(use_reloader=True)
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fl8jB.png)

```
    Markdown
    # Taipy *Demo*

    Value: TaIpY:text value="":tAiPy

    TaIpY:slider value="":tAiPy

    TaIpY:chart data="":tAiPy
```

How can I get the proper visual elements and not this syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taipy uses Markdown syntax as the default way to create a page. Having indent before visual elements will create this behavior.

Avoid having indent before your visual elements and they will display properly.

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui
from math import cos, exp

value = 10

page = """
Markdown
# Taipy *Demo*

Value: <|{value}|text|>

<|{value}|slider|>

<|{compute_data(value)}|chart|>
"""

def compute_data(decay:int)->list:
    return [cos(i/6) * exp(-i*decay/600) for i in range(100)]


Gui(page).run(use_reloader=True)
```

[image: Result]